# Get IPublishedContent To XDocument

Tags: c#, .net, umbraco

I am new to the umbraco world. I am uploading an xml file using umbraco. I have a method that parses xml document on the backend using

```
System.Xml.Linq.
```

I am trying to get that file into an XDocument.

On the front end I have the following call that returns data

```
IPublishedContent doc = Umbraco.Media(CurrentPage.XMLfile);
```

but I dont know how to get that into a format that I can parse.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use **TypedMedia** method to have strongly typed object and use it's properties to retrieve / load file (e.g. from URL where it's stored inside the filesystem on your server).

Check: https://our.umbraco.org/documentation/getting-started/backoffice/property-editors/built-in-property-editors/media-picker and then use your preferred way to load up XML document from specific location.

It will look like e.g (untested, but should point you in the right direction):

```
var typedDocument = Umbraco.Media(CurrentPage.XMLfile);

if(typedDocument != null) {
   XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
   doc.Load(Server.MapPath(typedDocument.Url));

   // ... do whatever you want with your doc
}
```